# Object comparison function, do not understand this example

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The example below is taken from an exercise at the end of Chapter 4 of [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/).

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
    return false;

  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;
  }

  return propsInA == propsInB;
}
```

Most of this function is easy enough for me to understand, but there's one part where I'm not really sure what's going on:

```
 for (var prop in b) {
        propsInB += 1;
        if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
          return false;
}
```

A for loop iterates through the properties in the provided object, "b", incrementing up the value of propsInB each time, and then I don't really follow why the if statement's conditions are what they are.

I'd appreciate any explanation.

Comment: It's checking to make sure they have the same number of properties.

Comment: You problem here is the recursive call to deepEqual(objA, objB) 
Recursive means it will call itself till the end. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32467720/5004923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets analyze them..

```
for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1; // Increment to 
    if ( 
          !(prop in a) ||  // exists in a???
          !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop])) // !! -> this is the point where recursion is happaning
      return false;
}
```

This checks if the property exists in a too.

```
   !(prop in a)
```

this is the point where recursion is happening..

```
!deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
```

Imagine recursion like you looking for the deepest document in a folder structure: /home/me/stuff/cool-stuff/games/..

you don't know the structure, but you have to find the deepest document, you will do it with recursion.

pseudo code:

```
  goDeeper(folder) {
    childFolders = findAllFolderInFolder(folder);
    if (!childFolders) {
      alert('found the deepest Folder: ' + folder);
      return;
    } else
      childFolders.forEach(goDeeper); // Call goDeeper for each folder in this folder...
  }

  goDeeper('/'); // It will go through all the filesystem, and each time it finds an end it will alert('...');
```

So this pseudo code would walk into each folder and try to go deeper and deeper..

Comment: Thank you, this explanation helped a lot. Given that 'prop' is the iterating item in a 'for' loop, would this also take the position of the element into account? 

For example, if I have a.y and b.y properties, but they're not in the same position in the properties list, I'd end up with 'not deeply equal', right?

Comment: No there is actually no position in objects, just a key map. They would be the same. the `prop` is the key as a string. 

you can access any object or array with obj['my_key'] you can also have keys like this: object = { "WTF, this is a really strange key": "strange value" }

But to answer your question, you don't have an concept of ordering like in an array.

Answer (score 1):

It's checking to make sure that the property it's found in `b` is also a property in `a`, and that the values of both properties are the same.

So, if `a` has properties "x" and "y", but `b` has properties "y" and "z", the test will fail for property "z", and it will fail for property "y" if `a.y` and `b.y` are not "deep equal".